# Trying to password protect graphite in apache but Internal Service Error

Tags: apache, apache2

I am trying to password protect graphite using apache. Below is the config in the sites-available dir.  Location of the admin password is in /opt/graphite/sec/.mypasswds.  When I restart apache I get a internal service error.  How to I resolve?

```
# This needs to be in your server's config somewhere, probably
# the main httpd.conf
# NameVirtualHost *:80

# This line also needs to be in your server's config.
# LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

# You need to manually edit this file to fit your needs.
# This configuration assumes the default installation prefix
# of /opt/graphite/, if you installed graphite somewhere else
# you will need to change all the occurances of /opt/graphite/
# in this file to your chosen install location.


# XXX You need to set this up!
# Read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGISocketPrefix
WSGISocketPrefix /etc/httpd/wsgi/

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName graphite
        DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
        ErrorLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/error.log
        CustomLog /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/access.log common

        # I've found that an equal number of processes & threads tends
        # to show the best performance for Graphite (ymmv).
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}

        # XXX You will need to create this file! There is a graphite.wsgi.example
        # file in this directory that you can safely use, just copy it to graphite.wgsi
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

        Alias /content/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
        <Location "/content/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        # XXX In order for the django admin site media to work you
        # must change @DJANGO_ROOT@ to be the path to your django
        # installation, which is probably something like:
        # /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django
        Alias /media/ "@DJANGO_ROOT@/contrib/admin/media/"
        <Location "/media/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        # The graphite.wsgi file has to be accessible by apache. It won't
        # be visible to clients because of the DocumentRoot though.
        <Directory /opt/graphite/conf/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Under Construction"
    AuthUserFile /opt/graphite/sec/.mypasswds
#    AuthGroupFile /opt/graphite/sec/.mygroups
    Require user admin
</Location>


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -2):

You resolve it by first looking in the Apache error log to see what the error is that Apache has logged about the problem. What you do after that will depend on what the error is.